TWA Screen orientation support not working
I'm trying to lock the orientation of my TWA.
Therefore I tried to set the manifest with the value according to this change
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/pull/127/files#diff-846bdc985456f51f19882dfb03ff7b63f029a97f40c887c0455be88ca2654a3eR183

<activity android:name="LauncherActivity"
    android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
    android:label="@string/launcherName"
    android:exported="true">
    
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.SCREEN_ORIENTATION"
    android:value="portrait"/>
</activity>

As you can see, the portrait value has been used to set the screen orientation. Therefore, it cannot be dynamic.
As far as I understood, the orientation support for TWA was added.
However when rotating my device, the app orientation is not locked and follows the device orientation.
Am I doing something wrong?
